# ST_MakeLine from ST_MultiPoint

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table with three points in it and I want to create a line from them using PostGIS.

[image]

when I try to create a line from this geometry using:

```
select id, 
       st_makeline(geom order by id desc) as geom 
from public."point_table"
group by id;
```

I get null geometery

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

PostGIS version 2.2.1 PostgreSQL version 9.5.1

Comment: Which PostGIS version?

Comment: Does each row in your table have a multipoint geometry that has only one member? In that case you are feeding only one point for ST_MakeLine and that's not enough for making a line. Remove id from your select as well as `group by`and you may have better success.

Comment: @JGH see edits.

Comment: @user30184, I tried that previously and again and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [doc](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html), this feature is not available in the version you are using.
You can try transforming the multi-points into simple points first, then creating the lines.

> Availability: 2.3.0 - Support for multipoint input elements was
>   introduced

Answer (score 4):

You want just one line, so remove the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select id, 
   st_makeline(geom order by id desc) as geom 
from point_table;
```

For a "real" example, if you have a table full of points from different lines, like:

```
CREATE TABLE line_pts (
  line_id integer,
  pt_id integer,
  geom Geometry(Point)
);
```

Then you'd group on the `line_id`:

```
select line_id, 
   st_makeline(geom order by pt_id desc) as geom 
from line_pts
group by line_id;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, saw your talk at FOSS4G and it was great! I tried removing the group by, but because it's an aggregate, it won't let me select the id field without grouping by it.

Comment: Of course not... you're putting three things into the line, how are the three ids supposed to fit into the one row of output? You could use array_agg to also group them up, I suppose.